# Is it OK to restore master db backup, after changing WSFC clustered instance into non-clustered instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm converting WSFC fail-over clustered SQL Server 2012 instance into non-clustered one.

My question in short: Is it OK to restore a master database backup taken from the clustered instance, into the newly installed un-clustered instance?

To achieve the conversion I've followed the instruction in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/install/add-or-remove-nodes-in-a-sql-server-failover-cluster-setup?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).

Basically I've removed all the nodes from the cluster, remove the cluster, re-install standalone SQL Server, then re-mount the previously shared NTFS volume locally and attached all user databases.

Then, I've transferred logins using `sp_help_revlogin`, linked servers, jobs, server roles, some permissions as shown in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/manage-metadata-when-making-a-database-available-on-another-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).

But still some things were missing from the re-installed instance, like permissions for system procedures, and these were stored in the master db.

Is it OK to restore the entire master db from the old clustered instance, or do I need to avoid such restore when some server configuration was changed, in my case un-clustered?

Comment: It is totally ok and allowed and you should be able to restore without any issue.

Comment: Thank you. I've restored the master db and everything seems to be restored now. I've followed [this manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-the-master-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure I called up the Microsoft support and they said this might work, but not supported. They suggested not to do it. According to the support guy there are some difference in system databases when clustered or not, and the difference can cause an error, and there are known such cases too.
And they gave me this [link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/manage-metadata-when-making-a-database-available-on-another-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)
So the answer seems to be no.